# Is "spell check" a function or functionality?

Tags: word-usage

[function](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/function) means

> the natural purpose (of something) or the duty (of a person)
>
> The function of the veins is to carry blood to the heart.

[functionality means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/functionality)

> any or all of the operations performed by a piece of equipment or a software program

[Spell checker - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spell_checker) says

> In software, a spell checker (or spell check) is **a software feature** that checks for misspellings in a text.

in this context, should I say

> "spell check" is a **function**?

or

> "spell check" is a **functionality**?

I guess the latter, I'd just like to make sure my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the two choices you've given I would say that technically spell check is a *functionality*. But really I think either could be used; you're unlikely to be corrected if you use *function* instead.

Which word you choose I think is more dependent on the sentence structure than on one word being more correct than the other. Personally I find the use of "a functionality" (setting up "functionality" to be countable) to be awkward if not actually incorrect. I would say either of these two are preferred:

> Spell check is a function of the software.
>
> The software includes spell-check functionality.

In the first sentence, depending on surrounding context, we may interpret "function" with your first definition of a "natural purpose" of the software. But we may also interpret it as meaning the particular bit of code within the software that actually does the spell checking – in programming, software is comprised of *functions*.

It's this second possible definition of "function" that makes picking one word over the other in this context somewhat unimportant: the spell-checking "functionality" is, in fact, provided by the spell-check "function".